# How to make checkbox determine if activity should be displayed or not

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

Simple explanation:

Checkbox placed in one activity (walkthrough) should determine if this activity is shown again at second app launch or not. Checkbox checked - activity won't be displayed anymore and app launch should start with MainActivity. What is simple trick to do that? Do I need to pass checkbox state from one activity to another in case of use sharedpreferences? I do not want to use any alertbox or dialog.

Here's my sharedpreferences attempt in Preshow.class (activity):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if(preferences.contains("checked") && preferences.getBoolean("checked", false) == true){
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            radioButton.setChecked(false);
        }
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(radioButton.isChecked()){
                editor.putBoolean("isShowOnboarding", true);
                editor.apply();
            }else {
                editor.putBoolean("isShowOnboarding", false);
                editor.apply();
            }}}
```

Code in MainActivity:

```
Boolean isShowOnboarding = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isShowOnboarding", true);

    if (isShowOnboarding) {
        //show walkthrough activity
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Preshow.class));
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: What seems to be the trouble? You should use SharedPreferences to store the value of checkbox, and based on that intent go to whichever activity you want.

Comment: check for shared preferences value before `setContentView()` method in `onCreate`. If checked use intent for next activity else continue.

Comment: @VivekMishra but how I check for shared preferences in Mainactivity class. I defined checkbox listener and attached sharedpreferences in another activity - preshow class.

Comment: Shared preferences can be accessed from any activity.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's rewrite your Preshow:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    checkBox.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("isShowOnboarding", false));

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            editor.putBoolean("isShowOnboarding", checkBox.isChecked());
        }
     }
```

See? Much cleaner. Notice that I changed the radio button to a checkbox, always use checkboxes for binary (yes/no) decisions. Also, I used the same SharedPreferences variable ("isShowOnboarding") for both checking and storing.

Now, if you want to skip this Preshow class and go straight to MainActivity, you'll need to create another class, one that retrieves "isShowOnboarding" and checks if its true and then decides if user will go to Preshow or Main. We usually use a "SplashScreen" acitvity when we need to load user data before actually starting the app.